# Keycloak Idle session not timed out in Angular because of background API calls

Tags: authentication, session, keycloak, openid-connect

My Angular webUI is integrated with Keycloak. It has background calls to .net RestAPI at 1-minute intervals. KeyCloak authenticates the connection.

Keycloak Realm SSO Session idle time is set to 30 minutes.

The problem is, at each API call, the session idle time is reset and in effect, the user is never logged out until the session max time which is 10 hours.

Appreciate any thoughts on solving this.